# Keybind в Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть combobox в котором 8 объектов, и я хотел бы чтобы нажимая кнопку (NUM1 например) выбирался 1-й объект, нажимая num2 2-й объект и тд. Если короче, то хотел бы забиндить выбор объектов в комбобоксе. Очень важно чтобы бинды работали в свернутом виде, когда программа неактивна.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это Xamarin, UWP, Avalonia, или что?

Comment: это дефолт windows forms combo box

Comment: Надо было метку ставить (я поставил), или хотя-бы в посте написать. Не один же winforms есть на свете.